# How to use csound granular synthesis audio in another sound engine?

Tags: realtime, granular-synthesis

This post is about using granular synthesised audio from csound to audaspace for an open-source vehicle simulation game in UPBGE (Blender Game Engine).

I would like to use the csound library's granular synthesis opcodes to simulate vehicle engine sound dynamically and in real-time.

Is it possible for me to use csound for realtime dynamic granular synthesis, and send the audio to another library such as audaspace?

I would be open to writing my own library or something to accomplish something like this, but I am very unsure where to start. Any ideas and alternative suggestions are welcome and appreciated!

Comment: I don't see this as being really a Sound Design question - I don't know whether it would be best fit for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ or 'the mothership' https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may indicate http://www.csounds.com/manual/html/CommandCsoundVST.html. The VST interface is made for real time control of a virtual synthesizer. You send MIDI events… and you get back a buffer of samples.

[I can’t comment on the previous comment (no enough reputation) DSP.stackexchange is about math behind signal processing algorithm… here, it is a PC library integration issue. Stackexchange seems adequate (there are some VST tagged questions)]